# how to change the django admin datepicker format?

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

I am using the admin's built-in datepicker, and I would like to change the default date format. In the DateTimeShortcuts.js file, it makes a call to `format = get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0];` which gives it the default '%Y-%m-%d' format. It does not appear to use the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS values in the settings.py file, so there does not appear to be a way to change them. It also appears to be hard coded to the first one in the list.

If I step into the get_format statement, it takes me into this file in firebug:

```
/admin/jsi18n/
    inline
```

I am not a javascript wizard and I cannot find this file anywhere in the Django directory, so I don't know how to begin in overriding these values? Anyway in that file is the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS array with only 3 values, which doesn't match the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS in the settings.py file.

A last tidbit of info. I am using the datepicker by means of the AdminDateWidget in a custom field:

```
class PartialDateFormField(CharField):
    widget = AdminDateWidget
```

Any ideas or suggestions for changing the date format for this javascript datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

I18N is generating js translation files based on the `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH`. Please follow [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#format-module-path) to see how to set up your own locale settings.

[Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.10/django/conf/locale/en/formats.py) you can see how these settings look like for *en* locale, which is set by default.
When you set your custom formats, admin will pick it up automatically.

Comment: That worked like a champ. I had a little trouble figuring out the 'full Python path'. If I put the formats tree under MY_PROJ directory (where the `settings.py` file is), then the full Python path is: `MY_PROJ.formats`.